# Can I use "filter by' with Map structure in hadoop - PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

provied that there's a Map like,,,

map.text

```
[key1#v1]
[key2#v2]
[key3#v3]
```

then, if I try to find 'value of 'key2'',

```
A = load ‘map.text’ as (M:map[]);
B = foreach A generate M#'key2';
C = filter B by $0!='';     // to get rid of empty value like (), (), ().
dump C;
```

is there any other way to find key2? with using 'filter by' only.

thxs ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `GENERATE` a field and then use it in a `FILTER`; you can include it in the `FILTER` statement to begin with:

```
A = load 'map.text' as (M:map[]);
B = filter A by M#'key2' != '';
dump B;
```

On your data, this returns one record:

```
([key2#v2])
```

As a side note, in case empty strings are ever valid values, the criterion you might rather use is `by M#'key2' is not null`.