# Filter map based on key or value in Apache Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

I cannot understand how I can filter based on either key or value in Apache Pig Latin

```
 a = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/timesheet2tuples.csv' using PigStorage('|')  AS (T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int),M:[mileslogged:int]);
 dump a;
 DESCRIBE  a;
```

Output:

```
((10,1),[70#3300])
((11,2),[70#3300])
((12,3),[60#2800])
((10,2),[70#3100])
((10,2),[70#3200])
((13,),[70#3300])
((14,),[70#3000])
((15,1),[80#3000])

a: {T: (driverId: int,week: int),M: map[mileslogged: int]}
```

Now,

How can I filter based on value or key, I cannot find an example [here](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/perf.html) or [there](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556902/can-i-use-filter-by-with-map-structure-in-hadoop-pig)

This works (based on [there](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556902/can-i-use-filter-by-with-map-structure-in-hadoop-pig))

```
B = FILTER a by (T.$0 == 10) AND (M#'70' == 3100) ;
```

But I am looking for a solution where I do not know the key/value.

something like this:

```
B = FILTER a by (T.$0 == 10) AND (m#value == 3100) ;


B = FILTER a by (T.$0 == 10) AND (m#key == '70') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pig 0.17, you can flatten the map, filter them and put them back to map.

```
A = LOAD input.txt using PigStorage() AS (T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int),M:[mileslogged:int]);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE T, FLATTEN(M);
C = FILTER B by T.driverId == 10 and M::value == 3100;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE T, TOMAP(M::key,M::value) as M;
dump D;
describe D;
```

Comment: Thank you @koji, I have  Apache Pig version 0.16.0.2.6.5.0-292 , will update it and test it with your approach,. This version throw an error on M::value

Comment: Koji, I have installed the latest version of HDP, i.e. 3.0.1, but still its version is "pache Pig version 0.16.0.3.0.1.0-187 (rUnversioned directory) compiled Sep 19 2018, 10:13:33 ", and of course is throwing the same error, is there any solution for this version